# Default template argument with specialized member function

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class template ***stack*** with default template argument and ***pop()*** function which is specialized member function

```
template <typename T,typename CONT = vector<T> >
class Stack
{
public:
 void push(T arg);
 T top()const;
 void pop();
 bool isEmpty() const;
private:
 CONT elems_;
};

template <typename T,typename CONT>
void Stack<T,CONT>::pop()
{
 elems_.pop_back();
}
```

//**specialized pop function**

```
template<>
void Stack<int>::pop()
{
 cout << "Called Specialized ";
 elems_.pop_back();
}
```

Main.cpp

```
Stack<int> mystack;
mystack.push(10);
mystack.pop(); ---> this calls specialized one Why ?

Stack<int,vector<int>> mystack;
mystack.push(10);
mystack.pop(); ---> this calls  template one Why ?
```

Comment: Both call the specialized one here - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/583a1e49d81c7ad0

Comment: please try with std::list 
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a37d6208449faba9

Comment: Why do you think it should call the specialized function in that case?

Comment: Because both types are same Stack<int, vector<int>>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your specialization thanks to default parameter is

```
template<>
void Stack<int, std::vector<int>>::pop()
{
    cout << "Called Specialized ";
    elems_.pop_back();
}
```

So both following call the specialization

```
Stack<int> mystack1; // Stack<int, std::vector<int>>
mystack1.push(10);
mystack1.pop(); // ---> this calls specialized

Stack<int, vector<int>> mystack2;
mystack2.push(10);
mystack2.pop(); // ---> this calls specialized
```

but non matching types would call generic:

```
Stack<int, list<int>> mystack3;
mystack3.push(10);
mystack3.pop(); // ---> this calls generic one

Stack<char> mystack4; // Stack<char, std::vector<char>>
mystack4.push(10);
mystack4.pop(); // ---> this calls generic one
```

Comment: Thanks @Jared42 for helping on this